# Signatures with Variables

Tags: outlook

I am sending a lot of emails based on a signature. There is some information in the signature that I modify manually every time. I am wondering if outlook offers some feature to make it easier.

I tried signatures, it saves a lot of time but it is time consuming to change all the text that is variable every time

What I am expecting is to find the best way to accomplish what I want. Which is having some kind of form where I enter all the variables that outlook would be able to position in the right place (Each field in the form would go to the right place in the message (I am using signatures for now)).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do that programmatically either when the signature is inserted or when  a message is sent.